# How to select node which has a parent with some attributes

Tags: xpath

How to select node which has a parent with some attributes.
Eg: what is Xpath to select all expiration_time elements.
In the following XML, I'm getting error if states elements has attributes, otherwise no probs.

Thanks

```
<lifecycle>
  <states elem="0">
    <expiration_time at="rib" zing="chack">08</expiration_time>
  </states>
  <states elem="1">
    <expiration_time  at="but">4:52</expiration_time>
  </states>
  <states elem="2">
    <expiration_time  at="ute">05:40:15</expiration_time>
  </states>
  <states elem="3">
    <expiration_time>00:00:00</expiration_time>
  </states>

</lifecycle>
```

Answer (score 4):

`states/expiration_time[../@elem = "0"]`?

Comment: This notation really helped me finding all the children elements (multiple different ones) from a given parent with an attribute equals to something!

//field[../@id = "FSCHA"] = returned all the field elements whose parent element had an id = FSCHA. But //*[../@id = "FSCHA"] returned all elements, not only fields, under the same scenario.

Answer (score 3):

**Use**:

```
/*/*/expiration_time
```

This selects all `expiration_time` elements that are grand-children of the top-element of the XML document.

```
/*/*[@*]/expiration_time
```

This selects any `expiration_time` element whose parent has at least one attribute and is a child of the top element of the XML document.

```
/*/*[not(@*)]/expiration_time
```

This selects any `expiration_time` element whose parent has no attributes and is a child of the top element of the XML document.

```
/*/*[@elem = '2']/expiration_time
```

This selects any `expiration_time` element whose parent has an `elem` attribute with string value '2' and that is (the parent) a child of the top element of the XML document.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all nodes having atleast one attribute

```
//*[count(./@*) &gt; 0]
```